# Photoshop to Flash quality loss issue

Tags: flash, photoshop

This is not coding specific, but the flash image im creating is for a website…

Anyway, When i import my .psd file into flash it looses quality. 
I have tried copy and paste individual layers from photoshop to flash - same issue.

how do i keep my crystal clear quality across the programs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tips:

- If it's vector artwork then, make sure it's being imported as vectors
- You could always use the `trace` command on rasterised artwork once it's in Flash, which should avoid qulity issues
- if it has to be rasterised, then making the artwork larger dimensions should help - but balance this with the increased downloading time a larger file will cause.

Comment: Ok will try these now and report back what happens, none of the images are vectors, there mostly photographs i've cut out in photoshop very very accurately. I'm a dab hand in photoshop if I must say, but flash just goes right over my head, i've tried countless times to get round it but I just seem to fall at every hurdle! 

Any who, will try your suggestions and let you know :) thanks very much trickwallett :)